# How to correctly initialize multi dimensional arrays dynamically in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception

Q. How to initialize arrays dynamically in Java?

I'm trying to store some metrics in arrays by using the following code.

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = in.nextInt(); // outer metric size 
    int [] n = new int[t]; // inner square metric e.g. 3x3
    int [][][] a = new int[t][][]; // e.g. 2x3x3, 10x3x3

    //input block
    for (int h=0; h<t; h++){
        n[h] = in.nextInt(); //inner square metric dimensions
        for (int i=0;i<n[h];i++){
            for (int j=0;j<n[h];j++){
                a[h][i][j] = in.nextInt();    //metric values
            }
        }
    }
```

results in Null Pointer Exception which in turn is an array reference expected error. Changing the arrays to fixed size, doesn't cause this issue as expected.

```
  int [] n = new int[70];
  int [][][] a = new int[70][10][10];
```

Therefore, I would like to understand the right way to initialize dynamic arrays.

Comment: You never initialize the middle `Array` section. `int [][][] a = new int[t][<here>][];` So you will have a container of null values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allocate a new `int[][]` in the outer loop. Something like,

```
n[h] = in.nextInt(); //inner square metric dimensions
a[h] = new int[n[h]][n[h]]; //add this
```

Comment: Thanks @Elliott. I've two statements that allocates memory to the array 'a'. First being int [][][] a = new int[t][][]; and second being  a[h] = new int[n[h]][n[h]]; From what I understand, Initially I had initialized a one dimensional array and the next statement is allocating a 2D array for the earlier initialization. I would like to ask, if this is a hack for my code or could it be a standard practice that I should be able to use going forward?